# Fragment getItem method return only when download finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I have `fragments` in my `View pager` and this is it's `getItem` method:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    fragmentPosition = position;
    Log.e("PageAdapter", "Creating fragment at: " + position);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("activity", DefinedValues.images);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("type", "info");
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.put("page", position+ 1 + "");

    String request = Json.stringToJson(DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo);
    DefinedValues.thumbnailInfo.clear();

    StringAsyncRetriever net = new StringAsyncRetriever();
    net.setListener(MyPagerAdapter.this);
    net.execute(request, DefinedValues.GET_DATA);
    Log.d(TAG, "got item @ " + position);


    myFragment = new fragment1();
    myFragment.position = position;
    return myFragment;
    //return null;      

}
```

Is it possible to return only when the `asyncTask` has finished without freezing the thread?

Comment: no, because returning when the asynctask has finished would mean waiting for the asynctask to finish, which would mean freezing the thread. Your fragment should use the listener mechanism you have to update its content.